# GPU doesn't work on new drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-geforce, display-driver

I recently bought a new GPU, it's an AFOX GEFORCE GT 610. It works ok after installing the drivers given in the CD it had with it. But the problem us that if I update the drivers or Windows 10 updates the drivers automatically GPU stops working.

Basically my GPU only works on the drivers that came with the CD not newer ones. Any ideas how to fix this?

It's so annoying and I actually am using Windows 7 because Windows 10 wouldn't stop updating it.

Comment: The latest drivers from Nvidia might work well: http://www.nvidia.co.uk/download/driverResults.aspx/119980/en-uk Windows 10 doesn't seem to insist on updating the drivers if you are actually using a version later than the version in their installer. The drivers from Nvidia claim to support your GPU.

Comment: @Mokubai I've already tried installing the drivers manually but doesn't change anything. It doesn't work.

Comment: As in the drivers don't install, or Windows still insists on updating them? "Doesn't work" is a pretty vague and unhelpful description.

Comment: @Mokubai the drivers are installed but they don't work on the GPU! It's pretty weird! If I install the old version that is on the CD Windows will update them and my GPU stops working after restart! That's why I am using Windows 7 at the moment. It's so weird Because the new drivers MUST work on my GPU also the installer checks it too so I can't install a wrong driver.

Comment: Weird indeed.  Seems that someone else has a similar problem with that specific card: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/afox-g%C3%A9force-gt-610-2g-ddr3/129b0ab2-db17-4f49-807e-fbac3d41bad4 I kinda guess that Afox have done something wrong and the Nvidia drivers don't properly recognise it.  There's a solution at the bottom of that post which looks to be to install the version you want then to use [`wushowhide`](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/2/f22d5fdb-59cd-4275-8c95-1be17bf70b21/wushowhide.diagcab) (from Microsoft) to disable the update.

Comment: I can post an answer if that works.

Comment: @Mokubai the final fix is to use the old drivers and use the hide tool to hide Nvidia driver updates?

Comment: Basically, yes. A bit sad, but sometimes with old hardware that's the best you can do.

Comment: Actually, I think the best solution here would be to return the card to the seller and get one that properly implements the Nvidia reference firmware, if that is possible at this point.

Comment: @Mokubai I thought there is a better way to fix this! Thanks anyways for the help! I'll try it, I'll install Windows 10 right now and hopefully it works right! Although it would still update the driver if I had stopped all Windows updates via registery so im not sure if it'll work right.

Comment: @acejavelin I don't think that's possible since it's not "not working" kinda

Comment: Personally, I would call that defective...

Answer (score 0):

Some of the older Nvidia-based graphics cards are not supported by their newer drivers.  You might try using only this site for downloading such drivers, since it checks whether the driver that would normally be used is compatible with the card:

http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Windows 10, at least, has a Feedback Hub program that will allow you to tell Microsoft about the problem in hopes of getting them to modify future updates to avoid it.

Just in case AFOX has designed their boards so that only drivers they provide will work, you might want to search their site:

http://www.afox-corp.com/en/download.asp